# How can we change the background color of a chart in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have written a code to generate chart using openpyxl, but I am not able to change the background color and legend color.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to provide as much detail as possible and explain what work you have already tried. Please read the following and update your question so others can help :) stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: openpyxl 2.3 was released today. It is possible to do what you want but you will have to familiarise yourself with the OOXML specification to do it. Alternatively, you might want to look at xlsxwriter.